# Any eventhandlers that apply to hidden elements?

Tags: web-application, javascript, xss, html

I'm trying to XSS a search field and my attack vector is getting reflected like this:

```
<input type="text" id="txtRpHiddenKeyword" style="display: none;" value="ATTACK VECTOR HERE" />
```

Only double-quotes are allowed and angle brackets are encoded therefore I can only use eventhandlers to execute my JavaScript. Problem is that display is set to none, therefore `onMouseOver`, `onClick` etc. won't work, so my question is, are there any other eventhandlers that apply to hidden elements?

Comment: You can try adding a second `style` attribute, that might override the 1-st one in some browsers (I haven't done any research/testing for this).

Comment: @Vatev I tried adding a second style attribute but it didnt work for Firefox

Comment: If you control the URL, you can probably use Chrome's [XSS protection](http://blog.securitee.org/?p=37) "feature" to strip out some code (e.g. `txtRpHiddenKeyword" style="display: none;`) ;)

Answer (score 2):

This vulnerability is exploitable in Firefox via [onaccesskey in combination with onclick](http://blog.portswigger.net/2015/11/xss-in-hidden-input-fields.html):

```
accesskey="X" onclick="alert(1)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this is HTML injection,  [this vulnerability is no longer XSS in the majority of browsers](http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?2,17217). This is because the element is invisible and there are no event handlers that will trigger on a hidden input element.

Comment: Opera uses to Webkit and V8 like chrome !
and it's not work on opera !

Comment: @Sajjad Pourali  aah good call,  I didn't test that exploit on the latest version of Opera.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you still use the onerror() event handler?

From the 6th post in the [link](http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?2,17217) posted in Rook's answer above:

```
<input type="hidden" value="INPUT" name="test">

take for INPUT this:

whatever" type="image" src="dontcare.jpg" onerror="alert(123)
```

EDIT - Though later in that same thread a post mentions that none of the methods discussed there work anymore.  So maybe not.